# How to give custom object delete permission to all users in org?

Tags: permissions, security, automation, delete, user-management

The user can belong to any profile or role. In future, any new user created with a new profile or with a new role, he/she will get delete permission automatically.

Please suggest a solution without code/trigger.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you requirement is `Any user can delete any record of that custom object`?

Comment: Right.....................................

Answer (score 2):

**Without code/trigger here is the solution**:

If anyone can access the record that means OWD for that object would be set to Public Read Only OR Public read/Write.

Now Go to all profiles-> Assign delete permission on the object and you are done. Now if anyone clone a new profile they will get this permission automatically also on that profile, until unless they remove it manually it will be there.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is `Any user can delete any record of that custom object`, then create a `queue` and update records ownership to that queue and every user would be a member of that queue.That's how he/she would able to get delete permission on records of that object.